# How to get the ZF classmap_generator.php via Composer without to install the whole Zend Framework?

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-autoloader, zend-loader, zftool2

Due to some issues with the dependencies (`zend-test` was prohibiting installation of PHPUnit 6), I removed the `zendframework/zendframework` dependency from the `composer.json` and installed only the Zend packages I really need. But now, the file `classmap_generator.php` is missing.

Now I want to get the classmap generator back but without to load the whole framework with all its deoendencies.

**Which package do I have to install to get the `classmap_generator.php`?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need the classmap generator at all, and it is removed from V3 anyway.

What you should do is remove any Zend Autoload configuration (if you have any in your `Module.php` files, and replace it with a PSR-0 or PSR-4 config in the `autoload` section of your `composer.json`.

This way, composer handles all the autoloading, and you can use `composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader --classmap-authoritative` for your production deployment, which will generate a very optimised classmap for you!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Just to add some further information: The Class Map Generator apparently was part of the `zendframework/zend-loader` package and has been removed (see also the GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-loader/issues/12)).